# Matplotlib Barbs as a function of time vs. height - unknown error

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, numpy-ufunc

I have data that has wind speed/direction for 16 different height levels. This data is recorded in 1 minute intervals. I am attempting to create a 2-d chart that has the height levels on the y-axis and time on the x-axis.

```
00:00, ws_10feet, wd_10feet, ws_20feet, wd_20feet,....ws_160feet,wd_160feet
00:01, ws_10feet, wd_10feet, ws_20feet, wd_20feet,....ws_160feet,wd_160feet 
00:02, ws_10feet, wd_10feet, ws_20feet, wd_20feet,....ws_160feet,wd_160feet  
...
23:58, ws_10feet, wd_10feet, ws_20feet, wd_20feet,....ws_160feet,wd_160feet 
23:59, ws_10feet, wd_10feet, ws_20feet, wd_20feet,....ws_160feet,wd_160feet
```

From this data, I have isolated the wind speed and direction into 2 (1440,16) arrays, one for u-component and one for v-component. I also, have `time_list` which is just a list with 1440 elements and my `level_heights` which is a 1-d array of 16 elements.

Put them together to plot:

```
...
ax.barbs([time_list,level_heights],u,v)
...
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

I am not sure what is going on or how to resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to display all 1440 times, you will have 1440 x 16 data points, so all the variables you pass to `ax.barbs()` should have these dimensions.

**Edit:**
I got it to work with your sample data using this shortcut mentioned in the `ax.barbs()` [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.barbs.html):

> **X, Y:** [...] If not given, they will be generated as a uniform integer meshgrid based on the dimensions of U and V.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

level_heights = [720, 700]
u = np.array([[ 36.10376018, -3.65789061], [ 35.96327862, -45.10811509]]) 
v = np.array([[ 36.58522244, -51.57043568], [ 36.44286749, -24.64179281]])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.barbs(u, v)

ax.set_xticks([0, 1])
ax.set_xticklabels(['start', '1 minute'])

ax.set_yticks([0, 1])
ax.set_yticklabels(level_heights);
```

[image: wind plot]

You may want to reverse the order of `level_heights` to make the plot more natural.

Comment: But I am only plotting wind on 16 levels and my data only is 1 minute winds for each level. Nothing in between. How would I expand that to a list of length 1440?

Comment: @Jonathon Impossible to say for sure without seeing the data, but presumably you could do it in the same way you got the `time_list`?

Comment: I have updated my question to include a sample of what my actual data source looks like.

Comment: @Jonathon Thanks, that helped me to understand the problem. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Could you copy+paste small data samples of the variables actually used in the function call into your question? E.g.  `time_list[:2]`,  `level_heights[:2]`, `u[:2, :2]` and `v[:2, :2]`.

Comment: In order: ```[datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 1)]
[720, 700]
[[ 36.10376018  -3.65789061]
 [ 35.96327862 -45.10811509]]
[[ 36.58522244 -51.57043568]
 [ 36.44286749 -24.64179281]]```

Comment: Ignore the datetime format. It is actually in my data as $H:$M:$S. I simplified it for the question above.

Comment: I just realised we don't need to bother with passing the dates and heights to the plotting function. See my updated answer.